# Objective-C : memory leak or not with multiple assignation with autorelease?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, autorelease, assign

If I do the following thing, will this make memory leaks ?

```
SomeClass* tmp;
NSDate* thetmpdate;

tmp = [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
thetmpdate = [NSDate date];
// Do something long with tmp and date

tmp = [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
thetmpdate = [NSDate date];
// Do something long with tmp and date

tmp = [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
thetmpdate = [NSDate date];
// Do something long with tmp and date
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no leak in the code you posted.
All objects will be autoreleased when the autorelease pool is flushed, no matter if the variable holding their pointers is changed or not.